# adding admin meta tag for facebook comments after the fact

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, admin, meta-tags

I added Facebook's comments plugin (HTML5) to my site, without the admin meta tag (like an idiot), then re-uploaded the site WITH the proper meta tag in place, but it's not showing moderator view when I'm logged in. If I use fb comments plugin at a different URL and include the meta tag on the first upload of the page, it works just fine and I see the moderator view when I', logged in.

I'm wondering if there's any way to set myself as the admin after the comments plugin has already been uploaded for the first time without the admin meta tag at a specific URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, the meta tag can be added later. Just think if you wanted to add or remove administrators.

First, make sure you're using the correct profile ID. If that's correct, and the meta tag is in place hit the Facebook Debugger at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. If you're the administrator, and you use the debugger tool, sometimes the internal Facebook cache will clear. If it doesn't you'll probably just need to wait for a 24-48 hours for Facebook to clear their cache.

Comment: Thanks man, this worked out perfectly, I now see moderator view just fine.